# Best way to do a lookup of a string in a table?

Tags: typescript

I have a table defined as follows:

```
export interface Answer {
  order: number,
  text: string
}

export class Config {
  answers:Answer[];

  mapAnswerTextToOrder(answer:string):number {
    return ( this.answers[this.answers.findIndex((value:Answer):boolean => {return(value.text == answer);})].order );
  }
}
```

The purpose of mapAnswerTextToOrder is to lookup the string `answer` and return its corresponding `order`. The code I have above is not right of ES5. I think I know how to rewrite it with a .map but it is already really ugly, it will get even uglier.

There's got to be a cleaner way to achieve the same thing in TypeScript. Anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it *today*

```
export interface Answer {
  order: number,
  answer: string
}

export class Config {
  answers:Answer[];

  mapAnswerTextToOrder(answer:string):number {
    return this.answers.filter(a=>a.answer == answer)[0].order;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. A couple of questions: isn't .filter a new javascript feature? Also I don't understand the line: "return this.answers.filter(a=>a.answer == answer)[0].order;" fully. In particular, the argument to filter is a callback which you are supplying with a fat arrow. But: can you tease apart the phrase: "a=>a.answer == answer"?

Comment: `.filter a new javascript feature` its ES5 (7 years old).

Comment: `a=>a.answer == answer` for a member `a` in `answers` its `a.answer` should equal the `answer` that was passed into the function